Forwarding subdomains to public DNS servers
I have an internal Windows DNS server with a zone example.com configured. I have several A records and everything works fine.
Now I have deployed a web app on CloudFlare with app.example.com domain that points to my public server. This works fine, too.
The problem arises when people using my internal DNS tries to resolve app.example.com. Since this record exists in CloudFlare, but not on my internal DNS, it returns ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.
How should I configure my DNS to resolve this issue? I thought forwarding some subdomains to 8.8.8.8 via Conditional Forwarding would help, but it seems to not support forwarding such queries (subdomains of local zones).
Thanks in advance!

Create a DNS zone for app.example.com in your Windows DNS server and add an A record for the root of the zone with the ip address of your web app.

My app is hosted on CloudFlare and I want app.example.com to resolve CloudFlare IPs. Unfortunately, it is not possible to provide server IP in the record.
